# Keeping variables between calls to a DLL

Tags: excel, dll, vba

I am writing an add-in for Excel to use in VBA. Is there a way to keep the variable values in the DLL between calls to the DLL. I made them global in the DLL, but the values don't remain between calls.

For example, during 'testing', I assign (within the DLL) an Excel Sheet to a variable 'HP'. When I run 'test2' to give 'zz' the value of "Home Page" using zz=HP.Name, it says object not variable or With Block variable not set. The HP variable seems not to be assigned that sheet anymore.

```
Public tester As Finance.Root

Sub testing()
    Dim tester As Finance.Root
    Set tester = New Finance.Root
    Set aa = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    bb = tester.startUp(aa)
End Sub

Sub test2()
    Call tester.trial(zz)
End Sub
```

And in the DLL

```
Sub test2(tt)
    tt = HP.Name
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Starting to feel like a broken record.  Show your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a new *local* variable called `tester` in `testing()`

Delete

```
Dim tester as Finance.Root
```